# print debug message in sqlplus program

Tags: bash, sqlplus

I want to print some messages before and after executing an sql file with sqlplus.

Here is my code :

sqlplus -s login/pwd@dbname << EOF
    echo 'begining sql file execution' 
    @/path_to_sql_file.sql
    exit;
    echo 'ending file execution'
    EOF

the key word echo can't print the debug messages in the terminal. I also tried print with the same result.

What is the right instruction for printing messages in sqlplus ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `PROMPT` to print a message in SQLPlus:

```
sqlplus -s login/pwd@dbname << EOF
prompt 'begining sql file execution' 
@/path_to_sql_file.sql
exit;
prompt 'ending file execution'
EOF
```

Comment: The quotes for the prompt text are not specifically necessary - all text after PROMPT and before the newline is echoed.